# PAM Winbind Expired Password

Tags: ssh, pam, winbind

We've got Winbind/Kerberos setup on RHEL for AD authentication.  Working fine however I noticed that when a password has expired, we get a warning but shell access is still granted.

What's the proper way of handling this?  Can we tell PAM to close the session once it sees the password has expired?

Example:

```
login as: ad-user
ad-user@server.domain.com's password:
Warning: password has expired.
[ad-user@server ~]$
```

Contents of /etc/pam.d/system-auth:

```
auth        required      pam_env.so
auth        sufficient    pam_unix.so nullok try_first_pass
auth        requisite     pam_succeed_if.so uid >= 500 quiet
auth        sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_first_pass
auth        sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_first_pass
auth        required      pam_deny.so

account     [default=2 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid >= 10000000
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup AD_Admins debug
account     requisite     pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup AD_Developers debug
account     required      pam_access.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_krb5.so
account     [default=bad success=ok user_unknown=ignore] pam_winbind.so
account     required      pam_permit.so

password    requisite     pam_cracklib.so try_first_pass retry=3
password    sufficient    pam_unix.so md5 shadow nullok try_first_pass use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_krb5.so use_authtok
password    sufficient    pam_winbind.so use_authtok
password    required      pam_deny.so

session     [default=2 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid >= 10000000
session     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup AD_Admins debug
session     requisite     pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup AD_Developers debug
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so umask=0077 skel=/etc/skel
session     optional      pam_keyinit.so revoke
session     required      pam_limits.so
session     optional      pam_mkhomedir.so
session     [success=1 default=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so service in crond quiet use_uid
session     required      pam_unix.so
session     optional      pam_krb5.so
```

Answer (score 0):

We'll need to know the numerical `uid` of the user you're logging in as to know for sure. What follows is speculation.

Authorization lockouts generally happen within the `account` stack , so let's start by looking there. Entries that terminate the module stack are immediately suspect. I don't see `done` anywhere in here, so the lines with `sufficient` are the ones we need to focus on. That lets us focus on these lines at the top of the stack:

```
account     [default=2 success=ignore] pam_succeed_if.so quiet uid >= 10000000
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup AD_Admins debug
account     requisite     pam_succeed_if.so user ingroup AD_Developers debug
account     required      pam_access.so
account     required      pam_unix.so broken_shadow
account     sufficient    pam_localuser.so
account     sufficient    pam_succeed_if.so uid < 500 quiet
```

- If numeric uid is <= 10000000 and a member of the AD_Admins group, the account stack will terminate with success line 2.
- If the user has an entry in `/etc/passwd` in addition to LDAP, the account stack will terminate with success at line 6.
- If the numeric uid is < 500, the account stack will terminate with success at line 7. (this is not likely the culprit due to your >= 500 check in the `auth` stack)

All of the above scenarios will result in the account stack terminating before the accounting checks of `pam_krb5.so` and `pam_windbind.so`.

Comment: The UID of the logged-in user > 10000000, no entry in /etc/passwd, and is a member of AD_Admins